# Look for a date object in database

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I want to get all events occurring on a specific date, but I can't get it to work.

```
Event buffer_event = Event.find.where().like("date",new_date).findUnique();
```

Here the new_date is a normal date object with the date 03/03/2016 09:00.
But I get an error when I try to run this line.

```
java.util.Date cannot be converted to java.lang.String
```

So I tried it with a string:

```
Event buffer_event = Event.find.where().like("date", "03/03/2016 09:00").findUnique();
```

But I get an error as well:

```
[PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant "Thu Mar 03 09:00:00 CET 2016"; SQL statement: select t0.id c0, t0.name c1, t0.date c2, t0.user_id c3 from event t0 where t0.date like ? [22007-187] Bind values:[Thu Mar 03 09:00:00 CET 2016] Query was: select t0.id c0, t0.name c1, t0.date c2, t0.user_id c3 from event t0 where t0.date like ? ]
```

So how do I get all events on that day out of my database?

EDIT:

```
@Entity
public class Event extends Model {

@Id
public Long id;

public String name;

@Formats.DateTime(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
public Date date;

@ManyToOne()
public User user;


public Event (String name, Date date) {
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
}

public String getName() { return name; }

public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

public Date getDate() { return date; }

public void setDate(Date date) { this.date = date; }

public static Model.Finder<Long,Event> find = new Model.Finder<Long,Event>(Long.class, Event.class);
}
```

Thats my event class.

```
    # --- Rev:1,Ups - df1003e

create table event (

id                        bigint not null,

name                      varchar(255),

date                      timestamp,

user_id                   bigint,

constraint pk_event primary key (id))

;



create table user (

id                        bigint not null,

email                     varchar(255),

password                  varchar(255),

role                      varchar(255),

firstname                 varchar(255),

lastname                  varchar(255),

constraint pk_user primary key (id))

;



create sequence event_seq;



create sequence user_seq;



alter table event add constraint fk_event_user_1 foreign key (user_id) references user (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;

create index ix_event_user_1 on event (user_id);
```

Comment: Post your `Event` class and also the DDL for the events table.

Comment: I edited the original post. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you probably should be using `.eq` instead of `.like` for dates. For querying have you tried passing in a `DateTime` object to the query? Something like this (untested):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("03/03/2016 09:00");

Event buffer_event = Event.find.where().eq("date", dt).findUnique();
```

Comment: That's it, all I had to do was using .eq. Thank you for your answer, i am still new to play framework.